# Where to buy football/quenelle/shell-like scoop/mold/mould [food presentation]?

Tags: rice, mold, presentation, plating

Some places serve rice in a football/quenelle/shell-like shaped scoop/mold/mould for food presentation. It's consistent at many teriyaki places so I suspect it's something you can purchase.

I've searched for the following terms: `football`, `shell`, `prolate spheroid`, `oval`, `quenelle`, in conjunction with `scoop`, `mold`/`mould` but haven't had any luck.

(Click images for larger view)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The closest I've found is a "*Deep Boat Petit Four Mould*", but the bottom is flat instead of a dome.

[image]

**Edit**: This is used to mold sticky rice, ideally they would have the 'shell like' ridges running longitudinally/lengthwise). All of these teriyaki pictures are from the Seattle area.

**Update** (2016-06-19): Found the mold in use in Japan. It's commonly used in *omurice*.

[image: omurice mold] (From this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uu5zGHjRaMo))

Comment: @clcto I'd upvote that if you made it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a technique called [quenelling](http://www.greatbritishchefs.com/how-to-cook/how-to-quenelle) where you form this shape using two spoons. It appears to be usually used for ice cream and other items of similar consistency but I don't see why it wouldn't work for steamed rice (although those would have to be large spoons).

Comment: i tried this before posting my question, sticky rice doesn't roll very well. in addition, this would be too slow for a high volume shop

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a good few available on Amazon. I just searched for "[quenelle mould](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=quenelle%20mould&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aquenelle%20mould)".

Comment: yep, found those but the one i'm looking for has 'shell' indentations and is about 125mm x 75mm (L x W)